# PDE with additive seperation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a problem with the following PDE:

$x^2u_x+\frac{1}{y}u_y+\alpha u=0$, for $x,y>0$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

With additive seperation:

$u(x,y)=X(x)+Y(y)$

Substituting in the PDE yields:

$x^2X'+\frac{1}{y}Y'+\alpha (X(x)+Y(y))=0$

Now here is my problem, I don't have an Ansatz to further solve, as I have no experience with additive seperation. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: We are asked to solve this PDE with additive seperation, multiplicative seperation $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$ and with the method of characteristics. I managed to solve using the last two methods, I only have a problem with additive seperation

Comment: Ok, I tried this Ansatz and get a suitable result in comparison to the other methods, thank you :)